# MYSQL after data duplicate data and insert (not duplicated)

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

i wanna migrate my origin database to new database(mariaDB)
but new database has some information
so i have to check

if some datas are in new database origin should not migrate to new one
i wanna seperate each situation, i wanna avoid

how can i check? just using sql query

Comment: Please provide sample data.  Your question doesn't provide enough information.

Comment: either add some unique index, or select only new rows before the insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at

- `INSERT ............ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` <---if you set UPDATE clause to do something useless, it'll do what you want.
- `INSERT IGNORE` <---- skip if duplicate.

I personally suggest the on duplicate key approach as `insert ignore` will also ignore some other errors and doesn't give you error message.

Comment: i think it's different what i want T^T but thx i learned a lot

Comment: if my answer couldn't help, you really should give a detail example of what you meant. Give some examples on what kind of data you're talking about. you question is too vague.

Comment: i have to... i give very small things... sorry

Comment: thank you this answer make me go back to home to take a rest